# OR Operator not working strictly in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I want a strict condition with update, but it is not working here. I mean if level1 user log in and update a from and submit by this fields belongs to level2 get empty.
My from user level from and entries them only. There are hidden fields also updating with null values. There is way to update only user level fields without effected hidden fields.

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['update'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tabl1` WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'];
    $query = mysql_query( $sql );
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $IndexNo= $_POST['IndexNo'];
    $ZoneID = $_POST['ZoneID'];
    $NameofCoordinator= $_POST['NameofCoordinator'];
    $GridNumber= $_POST['GridNumber'];
    $MobileNumber= $_POST['MobileNumber'];
    $StatusID= $_POST['StatusID'];

    $sql="UPDATE `tabl1` SET `IndexNo` = '$IndexNo',`ZoneID` = '$ZoneID'"; 
    $sql .= if($userName =='admin' || 'level1'){ ",`NameofCoordinator` = '$NameofCoordinator'"; }
    $sql .= if($userName =='admin' || 'level2'){ ", `GridNumber` = '$GridNumber'"; }
    $sql .= if($userName =='admin' || 'level3'){ ",`MobileNumber` = '$MobileNumber'"; }
    $sql .= ",`Keyword` = '$Keyword', `StatusID` = '$StatusID' WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'];
}
```

Comment: `'levelX'` is not a comparison

Comment: Also, your code is horribly vulnerable to SQL injection. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php For example, if `$_REQUEST['update']` is '999 OR 1 = 1', the query will update _all_ rows in the table.

Comment: What database field does contain level information (level1, level2 etc)?

Comment: @kingkero: Technically, it is - equivalent to `'levelX' == TRUE`, which always returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php :

```
$a || $b    Or  TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.
```

So, `$userName =='admin' || 'level3'` evaluates to `($userName =='admin') || ('level3')`, and since `'level3'` is not falsy, this will always evaluate to `true`.

What you probably want is

```
$userName == 'admin' || $userName == 'level3'
```

Comment: if level1 user log in and update a from and submit by this fields belongs to level2 get empty

Comment: @user3283373: Did you try the fix as per my example? Note that you need to change this in each of the lines.